# Memset and characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, memset

I aim to copy `source` string to `dest` string. If i compile the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char dest[6];
    char source[6];
    
    strcpy(dest,source);
    
    while (*dest) { printf("%c",*dest++); }
    while (*source) {printf("%c",*source++); }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get a runtime error. I suspect it is because `strcpy` copies from source to destination till it encounters `\0`. It did not,however,encounter the null character and kept on copying from the buffer till the runtime error occurred. To solve this problem, i modified the code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char dest[6];
    char source[6];
    
    
    memset(dest, '\0', 6*sizeof(dest)); //trying to set dest to '/0'
    strcpy(dest,source);
    
    while (*dest) { printf("%c",*dest++); }
    while (*source) {printf("%c",*source++); }
    
    return 0;
}
```

i get the following errors:

> prog.c:11:38: error: lvalue required as increment operand
>
> ```
>  while (*dest) { printf("%c",*dest++); }
>                                   ^
> ```

and

> prog.c:11:38: error: lvalue required as increment operand
>
> ```
>  while (*dest) { printf("%c",*source++); }
>                                     ^
> ```

Why does this happen?

Comment: That first program [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/2Zy1hx) for the same reason that the second one doesn't. Are you sure that that's the source you were using?

Comment: Also, you can't apply ++ to arrays. :-)

Comment: Rather, `dest++` is not legal C code if `dest` is an array.

Comment: "I aim to copy dest string to source string."  I assume you mean the opposite of that.

Comment: this line: `memset(dest, '\0', 6*sizeof(dest));` is setting 36 bytes.  All bytes after the first 6 are beyond the end of the array.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters it is the source array that shall be zero terminated if you are going to copy it in another character arrays using the standard C function strcpy. So instead of this statement

```
memset(dest, '\0', 6*sizeof(dest));
```

you should at least write

```
memset(source, '\0', 6*sizeof(source));
       ^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^
```

However even this statement is wrong because it overwrites the memory allocated for the array. `sizeof( source )` is already equal to 6 bytes as it is followed from the array declaration

```
char source[6];
```

Thus you have to write

```
memset(source, '\0', sizeof(source));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In fact there was enough to write either like

```
char source[6] = { '\0' };
```

or like

```
char source[6] = "";
```

or like

```
char source[6];
source[0] = '\0';
```

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. Thus you may not write for example the following way

```
while (*dest) { printf("%c",*dest++); }
```

Instead of this statement you could write

```
for ( char *p = dest; *p; ++p ) { printf("%c", *p); }
```

Take into account that nothing will be outputted because the array contains an empty string. You could initialize the source array with some non-empty string literal.

Comment: this line: `memset(source, '\0', 6*sizeof(source));` is NOT correct. `sizeof(source)` is 6, 6*6 is 36, so this would clear 36 bytes, with after the first 6 is beyond the end of the array boundary.  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest removing the `6*`

Comment: @user3629249 Did you read the entire post before writing your comment?:)

Comment: yes, I did read the whole post AND your answer.  Your answer is propagating one of the problems with the OPs posted code.

Comment: @user3629249 I am sorry but all these your comments do not make sense relative to my answer.

Comment: the first thing in your answer is to use: `memset(source, '\0', 6*sizeof(source));`  which will clear 36 bytes to `'\0'`  which will overrun the source buffer, which is only 6 bytes long

Comment: @user3629249 One more please read the whole answer. There is written all clearly.

Answer (score 1):

the following code cleanly compiles, and performs the desired operation.

The differences between the posted code and this are commented.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <string.h> // strcpy()

int main(void) 
{
    char dest[6];  // declared, containing garbage
    char source[6] = "12345"; // declared, containing the string "12345\0"

    strcpy(dest,source); 
    // now both arrays contain the string "12345\0"

    // best to use a 'for()' statement for indexing through an array
    for( size_t i=0; dest[i];   i++ )  { printf("%c", dest[i]);  }
    printf( "\n" );  // output the buffered data to the terminal
    for( size_t i=0; source[i]; i++ )  { printf("%c", source[i]);}
    printf( "\n" );  // output the buffered data to the terminal

    // note, the following lines contain a precedence problem in
    // the increment expressions and 
    // the address of an array declaration cannot be incremented
    //while (*dest) { printf("%c",*dest++); }
    //while (*source) {printf("%c",*source++); }

    //return 0;// with modern C compilers, 
             // this line is not necessary in a 'main()' function
             // when returning 0
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score -1):

`strcpy` is not a safe function, prefer using `strncpy`.

The error is due to the fact that you try to increment the array, which is an rvalue (i.e. a constant, you can not put it to the left side of a sign `=`).

The common approach to iterate over an array is to use a pointer like so:

```
char *p = dest;
while (*p) { printf("%c",*p++); }
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `strncpy` is not just a safer version of `strcpy`.  It actually does some very surprising things for historic reasons, and thus it probably isn't what you want in many cases.

Comment: As far as I remember the downside of strncpy is that it does not add the '\0' byte if the max size is reached, but it was not a problem here, since he was using uninitialized data, and seemed to me to just try and manipulate pointers and memory.

Comment: It also pads the destination buffer if the source string is too short.